# why my website is not responsive on cellphone screen?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I built my own web portfolio.Can someone help me to fix my website.it's not really responsive.The problem is i don't see anything change when i write media queries in the css.I also built some animation with javascript.the decorations will get off from the screen when we scroll the page.But if i open my website on cellphone screen.The font-size and the width of divs are not changing and the decorations are still on the screen.

here is my website : https://galih56.github.io/

The repo : https://github.com/galih56/galih56.github.io

Answer (score 2):

you need to add meta tag into you index.html head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```